# .NET MVC Best Practices to build a Model from and existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, ado.net

My MVC project accesses data using ADO.NET stored procedures. Most data that is returned requires a lot of formatting and much of it is used for business logic only and not displayed in a View. Currently we map it to classes in a folder called "Entities". The View Model needs to display the formatted values from multiple Entities.

I want to be able to take the data from the entity object(s), perform business logic and write it to the appropriate Model. Where do I write all this business logic?

### Current Folder Structure:

Entities (where the classes reside that match the database fields)

Repositories (where I call the stored procedures and map the results to the appropriate entities)

Models (The ideal structure and field names to be used by a View)

Views

Controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are no concrete rules for business logic regarding .NET MVC, your business logic generally goes in [the Model.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Fat models and skinny controllers are generally a good rule of thumb.

Comment: I agree. I like the "skinny controllers" idea.